# Normal Intercept with circle

Tags: geometry

Prove that the length of the intercept on the normal at point $(at^2,2at)$ of the Parabola made by the circle which is described on the focal distance of given point as diameter is $a\sqrt{1+t^2}$.

Hint
Equation of Parabola

$y^2=4ax$.

Focus is (a,0)

Equation of Circle is $(y-0)(y-2at)+(x-a)(x-at^2)=0$

Equation of normal is $tx+y=at^3+2at$

I tried finding other intercept point of circle with normal but getting struck but i tried to plot the said circle in desmos.com and found the intercept matching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The center of the circle is $\left(\frac{a(1+t^2)}{2}, at\right)$. The perpendicular distance of this center from the normal is 
$$\left| \frac{at + t\frac{a(1+t^2)}{2}-2at-at^3}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}\right| = \left|\frac{-at-at^3}{2\sqrt{1+t^2}}\right| =\left|\frac{at}{2}\sqrt{1+t^2}\right|$$
The radius of the circle is $\frac{a(1+t^2)}{2}$. Hence the length of the intercept is 
$$2 \sqrt{\frac{a^2(1+t^2)^2}{4}-\frac{a^2t^2(1+t^2)}{4}} = a\sqrt{1+t^2}$$

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply

Answer (score 2):

The circle described on the focal length of $P(at^2,2at)$ has y-axis as tangent.  The point of tangency is also the foot of the perp from focus F $(a,0)$ on the tangent i.e. at the y-intercept of the tangent line which is Q$(0,at)$. Let the circle intersect the normal again at R.

Now, we have $\angle FQP = \angle QPR = 90^{\circ}$. That makes the cyclic quadrilateral FQPR a rectangle. Hence $PR = FQ = a\sqrt{1+t^2}$